# Access a route, send an error alert, and redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I'm using nodejs, expressjs, javascript...

I have this "middleware" function to use when someone tries to access one route that doesn't have access when it is not logged in, but I can't send an alert, and redirect, as well as a response, how can I do it?

```
function isLoggedIn (req, res, next) 
{

    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    }

    res.send('<script>alert("You need to be authenticated to access this page")</script>'); 
    res.redirect('/');

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont recommend doing that (sending html in server side response)
Instead:
Send a json with a variable that will tell you in the client side to make an alert:

```
res.json({ success: false });
```

Ans then in the client side you can alert a message if !success and redirect.

Comment: Thank you so much!! You are right "dont recommend doing that (sending html in server side response)", thanks for the tip, I'm a beginner and this tips are the best! 

btw It worked! :D

Answer (score 3):

@Michael is right.

You should decouple the server logic from the client.

1. The server should know if you're logged in or not
2. The server should NOT know how you tell your users.

The middlwere should simple send 401 status if he's not authenticated. The client then checks if it was 200 (OK) or 401 (Unauthorized) and shows the user content according to the status

```
function isLoggedIn (req, res, next) 
{

    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
      res.status(200).send('Welcome')
    } else {
      res.status(401).send('You are not allowed')
    }           
}
```